Computation of the norm of Hadamard product of matrices
Suppose $U \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times r}$ is an $n \times k$ matrix with orthonormal columns $$U^{\top} U = I_k$$
Let $W$ be an $m \times k$ matrix.
We consider the matrix
$$N = UW^T \circ UW^T$$
where $\circ$ is the elementwise product of matrices.
We need to simplify the calculation the computation of $Tr(N^TN)$ using orthogonality of $U$.
My assumption is that it may be useful to consider the representation of $UW^T$ as a sum of rank one matrices:
$$UW^T = \sum_{i = 1}^{k} u_iw_i^T.$$
Then use the following:
$$UW^T \circ UW^T = \sum_{i = 1}^{k} u_iw_i^T \circ \sum_{i = 1}^{k} u_iw_i^T = \sum_{i,j=1}^k u_iw_i^T \circ u_jw_j^T.$$
Any help would be very appreciated
